# Custom Module, Extending WP with a Plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, framework, customization

I'm trying to determine the best way to expand on WP.

I love the base of WP for a website... it has pretty much everything needed for a website.

But now and again I need to be able to create some custom "pages" or small apps within the WP framework. For example, I've created a small app within a sub-directory of my WP install (/cart) for a purchase form. I'm including the WP head for access to the WP methods, but I don't feel that this is the most effective way of extending WP.

I've also looked into integrating other PHP frameworks like CodeIgniter and Yii ... again, I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Is there a way to create a WP plugin that has it's own "directory" or path? http://mywpinstall.com/customapp/

WP has so many great things going for it, that I'd love to be able to expand on it without touching the core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do that by creating a plugin that you can integrate into a page.

E.g. [mingleforum](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mingle-forum)  uses a shortcode, which you can use to create the forums. You create a page, with the URL you want, e.g. "CUSTOMAPP" page with URL "example.com/customapp", and then within that page use the shortcode to instantiate your app.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a shortcode. But this isn't really the best solution for more complex things like a purchase form with user registration built in... I haven't ruled it out though.

Comment: It is really difficult to answer your question then, because there are so many ways you can do that! I guess you could try converting it into a plugin, which would involve registering the required hooks and actions, and creating the administrative pages within the admin menu. Which way to choose (shortcode or rewrite), only you (or someone who knows what your app does) can decide.